# ASP.NET C# DataList - Find Hidden Field in Child DataList

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET. I have been trying all morning, but couldn't get this to work. In my DataList1, there is a child dataList (childList), which lists the Company names and checkboxes.  I also stored the CompanyID in the hidden field (hiddenCompanyID).

What I like to do is when the user checkes a boxes (under child Datalist), it will trigger the event (chkChildCompany_CheckedChanged) and capture the CompanyID from the hidden field so I can process the database update.  I could not figure how to find the Hidden field control with in the child Datalist.

Please help,
Thanks,

```
<asp:DataList BackColor="#ffffff" id="DataList1" DataSourceID="dsCompanyListPartialMatch"  runat="server" Width="80%" DataKeyField="Company1Word"
    UseAccessibleHeader="true"
    CssClass="books"
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="header"
    ItemStyle-CssClass="item"
    AlternatingItemStyle-CssClass="alternating" 
    GridLines="Both"
    CellPadding="0"
    CellSpacing="0" BorderColor="Black"
    ItemStyle-BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="0"
     HorizontalAlign="Center"
    RepeatDirection="Vertical" 
    >                
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr class="div_hover">
            <th style="width: 5%; border-right:1px solid black; border-spacing:0;  text-align:center; "></th>
            <th style="width: 5%; border-right:1px solid black; border-spacing:0;  text-align:center; ">Num</th>
            <th style="width: 70%; border-right:1px solid black; border-spacing:0;  text-align:center; ">Company Name</th>
            <th style="width: 10%; border-right:1px solid black; border-spacing:0;  text-align:center; ">Add?</th>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemStyle BorderColor="black" Font-Size="Medium" />

    <ItemTemplate>
        <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr class="div_hover">
            <td style="width: 5%; border-right:1px solid black; border-spacing:0;  text-align:center; ">        
            <asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Text="+" CommandArgument='<%#Container.ItemIndex%>'
                OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command"  
                Font-Underline="false"       
                Height="25"      
                Font-Bold="true"                  
                ></asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 5%; border-right:1px solid black; border-spacing:0; text-align:right; padding-right:10px;"><%#Eval("Row")%></td>
            <td style="width: 70%"><asp:Literal ID="litFoo" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Company")%>' /> </td>
            <td style="width: 10%;text-align:right;">
                <div style="<%# (Eval("CompanyID") == null || Eval("CompanyID").ToString() == "") ? "": "display: none" %>">
                    <asp:CheckBox id="check1" runat="server" />
                </div>

                <div style="<%# (Eval("CompanyID") == null || Eval("CompanyID").ToString() != "") ? "": "display: none" %>">
                <asp:HyperLink   
                    ID="HyperLink1"   
                    runat="server" ForeColor="Blue"
                    Text='<%# Eval("CompanyID")%>' 
                    NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("CompanyID", "/Apps/ERP/Other/CompanyInfo.asp?CompanyID={0}")%>'                               
                />
                </div> 
            </td>

            <asp:Label ID="lblRow" Visible="False" runat="Server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Row") %>' />
        </tr>    
        </table>      
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlChildView" runat="server" style="padding-left:200px;">
                <asp:DataList ID="childList" runat="server" Width="100%">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <div  class="div_hover">
                        <table class="table1" width="80%">
                       <tr>
                          <td style="width: 60%; border-right:0px solid black; border-spacing:0;">&#8226; <%#Eval("CompanyName")%></td>
                           <td style="width: 20%;text-align:right; "><a href="/Apps/ERP/Other/CompanyInfo.asp?CompanyID=<%#Eval("CompanyID")%>" ><%#Eval("CompanyID")%></a></td> 

                           <td style="width: 20%;text-align:right;">
                                <asp:CheckBox id="chkChildCompany" runat="server" value="123Test"
                                AutoPostBack="true"
                               OnCheckedChanged="chkChildCompany_CheckedChanged"  /></td>                          
                           <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenCompanyID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("CompanyID") %>' />                    
                       </tr>
                        </table>
                        </div>
                   </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:DataList>
           </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>           
</asp:DataList>
```

checkbox event

```
protected void chkChildCompany_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Process through child DataList (childList)
        //Capture the CompanyID from hidden field value if checkbox is checked;
        // Then I will update the database record with the ID....
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `NamigContainer` property to get the `DataListItem`, then use `FindControl`:

```
protected void chkChildCompany_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var chk = (CheckBox) sender;
    var item = (DataListItem) chk.NamingContainer;
    var hiddenCompanyID = (HiddenField) item.FindControl("hiddenCompanyID");
    // here you are ...
}
```

By the way, this technique works in all web-databound controls like `Repeater`, `GridView` etc. Using the `NamingContainer` is safer than using `Parent.Parent` or other approaches.

Answer (score 1):

A couple different ways to tackle this.  My first instinct is to cast sender to the appropriate type and then check the .Parent property.  That will probably allow you to do this:

```
HiddenField hidden = (HiddenField) myCheckbox.Parent.FindControl("hiddenCompanyID");
```

If that doesn't work... another option would be to embed a postback reference that already includes the appropriate hidden field value, which is triggered by the checkbox.  Or modify things slightly so that you've got a button there, which accepts a CommandArgument param.  In this case you'd just set it to <%#Eval("CompanyID") %>, and then that would be available in the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

I would add an attribute to your checkbox, and then obtain the value you need from the checkbox itself.

```
<asp:CheckBox id="chkChildCompany" runat="server" value="123Test"
                                AutoPostBack="true"      CustomAttribute='<%#Eval("CompanyID") %>'
                               OnCheckedChanged="chkChildCompany_CheckedChanged"  />
```

CodeBehind:

```
var CompanyID = (sender as CheckBox).Attributes["CustomAttribute"]
```

Comment: This is a great suggestion if it works.  However... I am a little skeptical!  Have you tried this, Andrei?  I am not sure the custom attribute will be persisted during the postback.

Comment: I have definitely used it before, the caveat i remember from doing this is that you couldnt access the "Attributes" property from some ASP controls, but I think with checkbox it works alright.

Comment: Also, if i remember correctly, as long as you declared the attribute in aspx, and not in code behind, it gets persisted, but i must admit I'm a little rusty on the subject nowadays

Comment: How can I upvoting for multiple answers?

Comment: You can only 'Accept' one answer, but you may upvote multiple useful answers, there is a little grey arrow that turns orange when you click it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Comment: Great, this is probably the best solution then -- it simplifies the existing code (why use the HiddenField at all?) and just one additional line on the back end.

Answer (score -1):

In your case, you should store the CompanyID in ViewState instead of a hidden field:

```
ViewState["MicrosoftID"] = "4536";
```

Later, you can access it like this:

```
protected void chkChildCompany_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string companyID = ViewState["MicrosoftID"];
    }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry, can you please show me how to? Is that going to be somewhere inside the childData? thanks

Comment: Can you show me the code for when you are storing the CompanyID in the hidden field please?

Comment: Dimo is barking up the wrong tree here.  Clearly CompanyID has to be different for every DataList row, otherwise why have it there at all.

Comment: what I mean is to store each companyID for each row in viewstate.

Comment: So if you store each companyID for each row, how would you know which one to use later in your code behind?

Comment: depends on which checkbox is checked.